# Scrapy: If key exists, why do I get a KeyError?

Tags: python, list, key, scrapy

With `items.py` defined:

```
import scrapy 

class CraigslistSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

and populating each item via the spider thus:

```
item = CraigslistSampleItem()
item["title"] = $someXpath.extract() 
item["link"] = $someOtherXpath.extract()
```

When I append these to a list (returned by parse()) and store this as e.g. a csv, I get two columns of data, *title* and *link*, as expected. If I comment out the XPath for *link* and store as a csv, I still get two columns of data, with the values in the link column being empty strings. This seems reasonable, as both title and link are attributes of every *CraigslistSampleItem* class. I would think, then, that I could do something like this (with the XPath for *link* still commented out):

```
  if item["link"] == '':
      print "link has not been given a value"
```

Yet the attempt to get the link attribute for each item fails thus:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 50, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
exceptions.KeyError: 'link'
```

If each item instance does indeed have a value for link (albeit an empty string), why can't I access this key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scrapy [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) class provides a dictionary-like interface for storing the extracted data. *There are no default values set for item fields.*

To check whether the field was set or not, simply check for the field key in the item instance:

```
if 'link' not in item:
    print "link has not been given a value"
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: class CraigslistSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
   ...:         title = scrapy.Field()
   ...:         link = scrapy.Field()
   ...:     

In [3]: item = CraigslistSampleItem()

In [4]: item["title"] = "test"

In [5]: item
Out[5]: {'title': 'test'}

In [6]: "link" in item
Out[6]: False

In [7]: item["link"] = "test link"

In [8]: "link" in item
Out[8]: True
```